# Smart Contract update Function

Tags: function, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

In smart contract I have add function like shown below. How to write update function for this?

```
function addEmployee(
     int empid, string memory name, 
     string memory department, 
     string memory designation
   ) public{
       Employee memory e
         =Employee(empid,
                   name,
                   department,
                   designation);
       emps.push(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the `emps` array where the desired `Employee` is saved, you can simply rewrite the value.

```
function updateEmployee(
    uint256 index,
    int empid,
    string memory name,
    string memory department,
    string memory designation
) public {
    emps[index] = Employee(empid, name, department, designation);
}
```

---

If you don't know the index and need to find it first, you can create a `view` function (callable without spending any gas fees) that searches for the index.

Here's an example search function assuming that `empid` is unique. If the `empid` is not unique, the function just returns the first found index.

```
function getEmpsIndex(int empid) public view returns (uint256) {
   for (uint256 i = 0; i < emps.length; i++) {
       if (emps[i].empid == empid) {
           return i;
       }
   }

   revert('Did not find');
}
```

Then you can use this index and pass it to the `updateEmployee()` function.